# Grouping Query Help in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My table `TEST` has the following rows:

```
test    | 1
test    | 2
test    | 3
```

How I query it to get the following result?

```
test    | 1 - 2 - 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Coalesce function to sort you numbers in a list. Hopefully this gives you a start:

```
Declare @T as Table (Col1 varchar(35), Col2 int)

Insert into @T(Col1, Col2)
Select 'Test', 1

Insert into @T(Col1, Col2)
Select 'Test', 2

Insert into @T(Col1, Col2)
Select 'Test', 3


DECLARE @X varchar(200)

SELECT @X = COALESCE(@X + ' - ', '') + Cast(Col2 as varchar(5))
From @T

Select @X
```

Comment: Can you query in one line in sql server 2005 query?

Comment: You would need to create a function to query the table for all col1 values. Then do something like this to use the function:

Select Distinct dbo.Function_List(Col1)
From testTable

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT x.column1,
       STUFF(SELECT ' - ' + t.column2
               FROM TEST t
              WHERE t.column1 = x.column1
           ORDER BY t.column1
            FOR XML PATH(''), 1, 1, '')
  FROM TEST x
```

Reference: [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: can u use this data for example

test    | 1
test    | 2
test    | 3